# How to dump the feature flags into a JSON file within the project folder when Gitlab pipeline runs

Tags: gitlab-ci, feature-flags

We need a way to have our `gitlab-ci.yml` create a JSON file with all our flags and their status inside, every time the pipeline is run.

I've been reading up on Unleash proxy and client SDKs for real time toggle status, but this isn't what I need right now. Just want to grab all flags for a given project and have the YAML create a JSON file.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I found [this article](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/feature_flags.html). Had to go under Project => Settings => General to get the project ID. Calling that API, can I see my test feature flags.

Now I just need to know how to access this API from inside the pipeline logic. Or maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Dump the feature flags _from where_, what's the source of that data?

Comment: I've created a few test feature flags inside my git repo, using the git lab UI @jonrsharpe

Comment: If you don't know the ID why not use the URL-encoded path option? And what does _"might have a syntax issue"_ mean; give a [mre], it's usually unambiguous whether or not that's the case.

Comment: Is there some specific problem taking however you access it _outside_ the pipeline logic and moving it there? All you need is an HTTP client (e.g. curl) then maybe something to process the response if it's not already how you want it (e.g. jq).

Comment: @jonrsharpe so i can create a curl call inside gitlab-ci if that's the best way to do it.  I think that's what I'm after is an answer that says, that is the way to go.